# Huawei USB modem not listed on connections menu after config with network manager

Tags: usb, usb-modem

I can configure my USB 3G modem.  It used to work, but no longer appears on the menu where Wifi and other connections are listed.  There are no errors with lsusb or dmseg.  Plus the USB device is mounted.  So what can I do to make the modem show up on the connections screen? Sometimes it works, other times it is not listed and I cannot connect.  I think maybe this is a Ubuntu bug that is not reported because not many people use 3G modems anymore.  But here in Latin America we do.

Here are the different outputs:

**lsusb:**

```
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 12d1:15ca Huawei Technologies Co., Ltd. 

dmseg | grep -i usb:  no messages

device is mounted:

/dev/sr1           32024    32024         0 100% /media/walker/BandaAncha Movil

Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS
Release:    14.04
```

Answer (score 0):

in terminal type

```
cd /etc
nano modules
```

this will open up modules file with nano editor. add this lines in the end of the file.

```
usbserial vendor=0x12d1 product=0x1c0b
```

where 12d1 and 1c0b are the vendor id and product ids gained from `lsusb` command.
logout and log in.connect usb dongle.